# Why do we use tables in email template.? shall we use tables and div together to create an email template

Tags: html, css, email, templates

I am a beginner in html and css,as I am doing my internship, I am often given an **email template** and asked to replicate it. Thing is, am not supposed to develop it **using div, but using table**. I read few articles [on this site,](http://www.litmus.com) to know why? but I don't really get some clear content out of it. Could someone explain the reason behind this.?

Answer (score 4):

Email design is different concept. In email template, `<div>` you can use but it will not support. `<table>` is basic html component you can use almost all properties of table.

Following is usefull link you can refer for email template design.

http://www.activecampaign.com/email-design-guide/

Comment: Thank you so much for the share.